# Eclipse Warning "Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-17."

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver

I am taking a udemy course "Selenium Webdriver with Java for Beginners" and have done all of the setup from the course, but I cannot for the life of me get rid of this warning in eclipse. I verified I have java18.0.1.1 installed on my mac, edited the build path in eclipse to point to the 18.0.1.1 jdk.  The issue is, the JRE system library keeps reverting to JavaSE-17, which afaik isnt installed on my machine.  It happens every time I click update maven project.

In my pom.xml file, I have the below maven plugin, specifying java18...

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>18</source>
          <target>18</target>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-17. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.

[Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfB0f.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of Java 18 requires **both** Eclipse 2022-03 and [this](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-18-support-eclipse-2022-03-423) patch from the Marketplace. 2022-03 came out a week before Java 18 (March 16th vs. March 22nd), so it can not officially claim to support it. The patch should be uninstalled before updating to 2022-06 later this month.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this block in your pom.xml.

```
  <properties>
    ...
    <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

If it doesn't work check the official manual about Maven's POM.xml [here](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html)

Make sure that you also have a correct Maven path at your Mac.

Comment: Thanks, I added that property earlier, but the warning still comes back whenever I update the maven project

Comment: Have you always had java 18 on your computer? What version you have in Window - Preferences - Java - Installed JRE? You may change it by Execution Environment there. If there is 18, try to change to the version that your error asks for

Comment: I manually installed java 18 before I installed eclipse.  I have java 18 sdk selected as my installed jre in eclipse.

Comment: Ok, do you refresh maven or restart your eclipse? That's probably not the problem, but you should to try. It's hard to understand why you have this error

Comment: Ive tried both, restarting eclipse and refreshing maven project...seems like it may be a maven issue?

Comment: I suppose it's in the eclipse/jdk settings. Try to check Build Path - User Libraries in Window - Preferences. Do you have any folders there? And check there in Execution Environments that you have a mark in front of JDK18